# In Elixir, how do I format a DateTime relative to now?

Tags: elixir

I recall finding something that lets you convert a DateTime to a string like "in 1 hour", but my searches so far have come up empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in `Timex`

https://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.html?#from_now/1
This does what you want

Comment: Suggesting `Timex` in 2021 looks a bit npm-ish to me.

Comment: Well, diffing datetime is not part of the standard lib. Pick a poison of your choice.

Comment: https://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.Format.DateTime.Formatters.Relative.html has the functionality if anyone is using timex

Answer (score 5):

[ex_cldr_dates_times](https://github.com/elixir-cldr/cldr_dates_times) also has the capability, including localisation.

```
iex> Cldr.DateTime.Relative.to_string(~U[2017-04-29 09:00:00Z], relative_to: ~U[2017-04-29 08:00:00Z])            
{:ok, "in 1 hour"}
iex> Cldr.DateTime.Relative.to_string(~U[2017-04-29 09:00:00Z], relative_to: ~U[2017-04-29 08:00:00Z], locale: "de")
{:ok, "in 1 Stunde"}
iex> Cldr.DateTime.Relative.to_string(~U[2017-04-29 09:00:00Z], relative_to: ~U[2017-04-29 08:00:00Z], locale: "ja")
{:ok, "1 時間後"}
iex> Cldr.DateTime.Relative.to_string(~U[2017-04-29 09:00:00Z], relative_to: ~U[2017-04-29 11:05:00Z])              
{:ok, "2 hours ago"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize the strings a bit more it's easy to construct your own strings as well. E.g. short versions using "3h" instead of "3 hours" and so on:

```
def from_now_short(now \\ DateTime.utc_now(), later) do
    diff = DateTime.diff(now, later)
    cond do
      diff <= -24 * 3600 -> "in #{div(-diff, 24 * 3600)}d"
      diff <= -3600 -> "in #{div(-diff, 3600)}h"
      diff <= -60 -> "in #{div(-diff, 60)}m"
      diff <= -5 -> "in #{-diff}s"
      diff <= 5 -> "now"
      diff <= 60 -> "#{diff}s ago"
      diff <= 3600 -> "#{div(diff, 60)} minutes ago"
      diff <= 24 * 3600 -> "#{div(diff, 3600)}m ago"
      true -> "#{div(diff, 24 * 3600)}d ago"
    end
end
```